# How to do different checks in UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I try to do few checks in a function of UITextFieldDelegate and I'm really stuck.
In one check I want to verify if the user try to insert spaces at the front of the UITextfield and to don't allow him.
In another check I want to limit the user to enter only numbers and punctuation for a price UITextfield.

Is ok if I'm doing the checks there ?

Here is my code:

```
class AdminPanelViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var productNameTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var productPriceTextfield: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        productPriceTextfield.delegate = self
        productNameTextfield.delegate = self
    }

}

extension AdminPanelViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

    // Function which allow the user to enter only digits and punctuation for Price textfield
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {

        // This is for my Product Name and I want it here also
        if (productNameTextfield!.text != nil){

            if Int(range.location) == 0 && (string == " ") {
                return false
            }
            else{
                return true
            }
        }

        else if (productPriceTextfield!.text != nil) {

            // This is for my price and I need it here
            let allowedCharacters = "0123456789."
            return allowedCharacters.contains(string) || range.length == 1

        }

        return WHAT TO RETURN ???
    }

}
```

Thank you for your time !!!

Comment: `return true` to allow edit for any other text field

Comment: If I return `true` then my price TextField will allow letters. I tried.

Comment: set keyboard type to `decimalPad` for the textfield that is for price as `productPriceTextfield.keyboardType = .decimalPad`

Comment: `WHAT TO RETURN` should always be `true`.

Comment: Yes I set my price textfield as `productPriceTextfield.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation`. But I have problems with spaces.

Comment: for price and punctuation you can change keyboard type to number pad in attribute inspector

Comment: why you want punctuation pad for price?

Comment: @Kamran because the price need to be Float.

Comment: So, `decimalPad` does not allow float?

Comment: `numbersAndPunctuation` can be used on Simulator. `decimalPad` is not working for me on Simulator, only on my physical iPhone.

Comment: It might look grey/disabled but it works on tap in simulators. Anyway you should only be worried about space issue for `Name textfield` if you set `Price textfield` `keyboard` type to`.decimalPad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check `textField` to see whether you have the right one, like this:

```
if (textfield == productNameTextfield) {
  // DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change keyboard type to numberPad for price

```
productPriceTextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
```

and for space use trim method this way :

```
let str = productNameTextfield!.text
let trimmed = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```